# Turning a precompiled web app to a 'normal' web app

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, compilation

I've got a quick question about precompiled web apps:

I've recently took over a project done by someone else, which is a precompiled web app. This means that it has no App_Code folder, of course. Due to the nature of this project I would like to put my code on the server anyhow.

I can't just add the code, because I'll get an Exception stating that the App_Code folder isn't allowed  because it's a precompiled web app. If I remove the file 'PrecompiledApp.config", then my application crashes.

So what are the correct steps in turning a precompiled web app to a compile-on-demand webapp?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can get this working in VS2010.

Go to your web app settings and select the Package  / Publish Web tab. There's a drop down that's probably defaulted to 'Only files needed to run this application'. If I use this it just publishes the compiled DLLs to the server and the web files, but none of the code.

If I change this to 'All files in the project folder' then I get everything - all the C# code for my controllers, for example.

Of course whether you would want your production code on a server is a different question, and you also get all the VS solution files and stuff like that too so it looks quite messy.

Comment: No, that's the thing. We don't publish our websites using the publish-tool in Visual Studio, but we simply upload all that's necessary. Especially for this project, where I want to have a very tight control over what gets uploaded and what not, I would like to keep it this way. 

So I guess, a better way to rephrase the question would be to say: "what do I have to do, in order to be able to upload the APP_Code folder and get control over what is launched and what not"

Comment: May I suggest that you vote to close this question and ask a new one with the more specific phrasing that you have just stated? You might get a better response that way.